# How to fill an image in an imageView in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an image saved in my database that is passed to an image as a byte array and then loaded to the Image view. However, I can't get it to fill the imageView. I use the following code:

```java
package com.example.AppPrototipo.ui.tourist;

imports...

@Component
public class ExperienceController {

    @FXML
    Pane imagePane;

    @FXML
    ImageView imageViewPrincipal;

    private final ExperienceRepository experienceRepository;

    public ExperienceController(ExperienceRepository experienceRepository) {
        this.experienceRepository = experienceRepository;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){

        Experience experience = experienceRepository.findById(1);

        Image image = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(experience.getImages().get(0).getImageData()));
        imageViewPrincipal.setImage(image);
        imageViewPrincipal.fitWidthProperty().bind(imagePane.widthProperty());
        imageViewPrincipal.fitHeightProperty().bind(imagePane.heightProperty());


    }
}
```

This is the result i get:
[image: Image in imageView but not filling the right side]

The desired result would be that the image fills the whole width (fill the black side) by cropping the top and bottom sides and remaining centered. Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: From the [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) docs it sounds like you don't want to set both the fitWidth and the fitHeight. You should probably just do fitWidth. What do you want to happen if the image is slim enough that the width is fit, but the height isn't enough to fill the screen?

Comment: @matt oh I didn't know that. I'll try it. Thanks!
Regarding your question, the idea is that the image should crop on the sides to compensate

Comment: Note that there are attributes in [css for background images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) that provide a lot of flexibility in display and sizing treatment of inages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're setting the preserveRatio property to true on the ImageView, and as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067492/matt) stated is his comment, you only need to set one of them, say fitWidth, and the fitHeight will be calculated using the image ratio.

the problem is that the ratios of the image and the pane don't match so you need to do some cropping using [setViewport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setViewport-javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D-), and it would be best to do the cropping when the pane's height or width change.

What you need to do is to calculate the ratio of the image, and compare it to the ratio of the pane, the comparison will let you decide whether to keep the original width or original height of the image, and you'll calculate the other using the pane's ratio.

Not really sure if that's the best practice but here's the code for what i have described

```
    double oldImageWidth = image.getWidth(), oldImageHeight = image.getHeight();            //saving the original image size and ratio
    double imageRatio = oldImageWidth / oldImageHeight;

    imageViewPrincipal.setImage(image);

    ChangeListener<Number> listener = (obs, ov, nv) -> {
        double paneWidth = imagePane.getWidth();
        double paneHeight = imagePane.getHeight();

        double paneRatio = paneWidth / paneHeight;                                          //calculating the new pane's ratio 
                                                                                            //after width or height changed
        double newImageWidth = oldImageWidth, newImageHeight = oldImageHeight;
        
        if (paneRatio > imageRatio) {
            newImageHeight = oldImageWidth / paneRatio;
        } else if (paneRatio < imageRatio) {
            newImageWidth = oldImageHeight * paneRatio;
        }
        
        imageViewPrincipal.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(                                     // The rectangle used to crop
                (oldImageWidth - newImageWidth) / 2, (oldImageHeight - newImageHeight) / 2, //MinX and MinY to crop from the center
                newImageWidth, newImageHeight)                                              // new width and height
            );
        
        imageViewPrincipal.setFitWidth(paneWidth);
    };

    imagePane.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
    imagePane.heightProperty().addListener(listener);
```

And here is how it looks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It totally worked! You sir are a genius. Thank you very much!